# How to fix my email address on Careers 2.0

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, email

I accidentally entered a 'wrong' email address when creating my Careers 2.0 profile. This is probably because I signed in using Google where I normally use OpenID for Stack Overflow. Now I cannot link to questions on Stack Overflow, and I cannot change my email address (the system tells me the address has been taken).
How do I link my Careers 2.0 profile to my other Stack Exchange sites accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be all set, your account is now properly linking to your SE sites.

Comment: Thanks Korneel! I guess this means it is not something I could have fixed myself (other than thinking before signing up).

Comment: @Han Nope... it was a backend thing that can happen when someone uses different credentials for SO and Careers.